# How to exclude the column from csv which is there in Grid?

Tags: csv, web2py

How to exclude the column from csv which is there in web2py Grid while export to csv?

```
self.rows.export_to_csv_file(s, represent=True, write_colnames=False)
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the `export_to_csv_file` method manually rather than using the grid'd built-in CSV download functionality, that method takes a `colnames` argument, which allows you to specify whichever columns you want to include (it defaults to all columns in the `Rows` object).